# How to rewrite this code in lambda Python and assign it to CidrIP parameter in IpPermissions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ip-address

I need to rewrite this code in Python lambda to get the client IP 
    and assign it to `CidrIp` parameter of `authorize_ingress` function. Please any suggestions on doing this in Python lambda 3.7

```js
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('SourceIP =', event.sourceIP);
    callback(null, event.sourceIP);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is node.JS translating it to python shouldn't be hard.

Will the following work for you?

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('SourceIP =' + event['sourceIP']);
    return event['sourceIP']
```

Comment: I have tried the above function and its giving me timed out error and also i guess the returned value is in object ..How do i convert it in to string to assign it to CidrIp attribute in IpPermissions `sg.authorize_ingress(IpPermissions=[{"IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": 90, "ToPort": 90, 
      "IpRanges": [{"CidrIp": event.sourceIP, "Description": description}]}])` will this work??

Comment: Is there anything else in the logs? Can you see if the print statement is actually executing?

Comment: `{
  "errorMessage": "'sourceIP'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 20, in lambda_handler\n    print('SourceIP =' + event['sourceIP']);\n"
  ]
}` Sir this is the error i am recieving now

Comment: clientIp = event["requestContext"]["identity"]["sourceIp"] How about this ?

Comment: `{
  "errorMessage": "'requestContext'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 20, in lambda_handler\n    clientIp = event[\"requestContext\"][\"identity\"][\"sourceIp\"]\n"
  ]
}` this is the error for above command is there any way around this?

Comment: Looks like there is no key SourceIp in your event variable. Maybe add a print(event) to see what’s the right key?

Comment: Glad I could help!